# onCreateContextMenu function not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-activity, contextmenu

When I am calling a new activity through onListItemClick function the long press functionality (onCreateContextMenu function) is not working. If I comment the code inside the try catch code fragment in onListItemClick function the onCreateContextMenu works perfectly. But i have to use both functions for different purposes.

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitems));

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    registerForContextMenu(v);
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contacts_list.class);
        intent.putExtra("GroupName", listitems[position]);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Details");
    menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Delete");

}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: It dose not crash but it opens new Activity even though when I long press the listview item.

Answer (score 0):

First, context menus are not especially popular -- it is an old UI style.

That being said, the proper way to use a context menu with a `ListView` is:

1. Call `registerForContextMenu()`, passing in *the `ListView`*, from `onCreate()` of your activity (or `onCreateView()` of your fragment) (side effect: get rid of your `registerForContextMenu()` call in `onListItemClick()`)
2. In `onContextItemSelected()`, do whatever you want based on the context menu that was chosen

To find out in `onContextItemSelected()` what row the user had long-pressed to bring up the menu, call `getMenuInfo()` on the `MenuItem` passed into `onContextItemSelected()`, cast that object to be an `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo`, and look at the `position` data member:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=
          (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

// then do something with info.position
```

Comment: View v = new View(this);
registerForContextMenu(v); tried this on onCreate() and removed from onListItemClick(), but having same problem onCreateContextMenu() function is not being called.

Comment: @MubashirAliMemon: Call `registerForContextMenu()`, passing in **the `ListView`**, from `onCreate()` of your activity.

Comment: "First, context menus are not especially popular -- it is an old UI style." Can you please explain why are they an old style? And what modern and correct alternatives for them should we use?

Comment: @HarryCater: "Can you please explain why are they an old style?" -- https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html "And what modern and correct alternatives for them should we use?" -- contextual action bar (a.k.a., action mode) is the recommended alternative.